# Positive definite sequence and its corresponding determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, moment-problem

I am currently reading the book of Akhiezer http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf and I saw on page 1 that a  sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ of real numbers  is  positive definite if $$ \sum_{i,j=0}^{n}s_{i+j}c_ic_j \ge 0,$$ for any $n\ge 0$ and $c_0, c_1,\cdots,c_n \in \mathbb{R}.$

He now further said that the the positive property of this sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is equivalent to the fact that the all determinants   $D_n$ of each associated Hankel matrix
 $$H_n=(s_{i+j})_{0\le i,j \le n},$$ $D_n= \det(H_n)> 0$ for all $ n\ge 0$.

My question is why is this determinant positive for $n> 0$.

[image]

Comment: Your example is irrelevant, as the matrix is not a Hankel matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have corrected it

Comment: What if $s_n=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Although I can't open the pdf in the link, looking at the cached version I think that the definition in this post should read a little differently.  The quadratic hankel form that Jaynot gives is supposed to be positive definite, so it should read as **strictly** greater than zero for arbitrary **nonzero** $c$. Otherwise none of this makes sense!

Comment: I just uploaded the page that shows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H_k$ be the $k$th Hankel matrix of the sequence.

**For the forward direction of the equivalence**, we use the fact that positive definiteness of each $H_k$ individually implies positive determinant of $H_k$.
In more detail:
Akhiezer defines a positive sequence as one in which every quadratic (Hankel) form is positive definite.  This translates to $c^T H_k c > 0$ for all nonzero $c$. For example in the case $k=2$, the quadratic form is $s_0c_0^2 + 2s_1c_0c_1 + s_2c_1^2 = c^T H_2 c$.

Now let $c$ be any eigenvector of $H_k$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ ($c$ is nonzero by definition of eigenvector). Then $0 < c^T H_k c = c^T \lambda c = \lambda |c|^2,$ which shows $\lambda > 0.$ so all eigenvalues of $H_k$ are greater than 0, and the determinant of $H_k$, which is the product of its eigenvalues, is positive. Note that this argument is not specific to Hankel or even symmetric matrices, in general, positive definiteness implies positive determinant.

**The other direction** follows immediately from Sylvester's Criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)
, which characterizes positive definite matrices as having all their leading minors positive (necessarily and sufficiently).

For $n \geq k$ we  find $H_k$ embedded in $H_n$ as the $k$th leading minor of $H_n$.  Assuming that $H_i$ for $i \leq n$ has positive determinant, Sylvester's Criterion implies that $H_n$ is positive definite.
Since $H_k$ by assumption has positive determinant for all $k$, this shows that all Hankel matrices of the sequence are positive-definite.

Comment: Thank you Badam. I am still a bit confused why this determinant is positive. Could you please explain the forward implication?

Comment: For example the case $n=2$, why is $Det (H_2) = s_0s_2 - s_1^2 > 0$

Comment: edited answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you Badam. I read through your answer and it made a lot of sense to me. Thanks a lot.